# Show Ionic3 LoadingController partially

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, loading, ionic3

We know that the LoadingController in ionic3 is a fullscreen loading. Is it posiible user the LoadingController for partial loading like loading only a list in the screen of a card in the screen?

Answer (score 2):

```css
ion-spinner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. You need to create a custom loader for that.

Here is an [**example of the doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#usage)

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
  const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `
      <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box"></div>
      </div>`,
    duration: 5000
  });

  loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed loading');
  });

  loading.present();
}
```